# How to get Bundle Product Selected Options From Quote

Tags: magento2, rest-api, bundle-product

I am creating a Custom APi to retrieve products in cart how can i get the bundle product details as displayed in web currently how i do this

```
$childrens = $item->getChildren();
    public function getBundleData($childrens) {
        $data = [];
        $count = 0;
        foreach($childrens as $children) {
            $data[$count]['id'] = $children->getId();
            $data[$count]['name'] = $children->getName();
            $data[$count]['price'] = $children->getData('price_incl_tax');
            $data[$count]['quantity'] = $children->getQty();
            $count++;             
        }
        return $data;
    }
```

But I also want to get the option label option id selected option Id etc as displayed in below figure please help thanks in advanced

[image]